# Making the column height same and remove extra content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question, my webpage has many div section and have multiple ul li.
It is 2 column design and what i need to do is to set the same height for both corresponding div section.
For example check the image, it is one section and what i want is to set the height for the shortest div and remove the large div content. Is this possible to do?

I checked on internet but what i am getting is to set the both column height but unable to find how can i remove the content.

The right image is what i want.

Please help :)

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused. Did you want to set a max height for both and make sure the DIVs don't show extra content beyond that?

Comment: 1) Make the large `DIV`'s `height` equal to the `height` of shortest one. 2) Give a `overflow-y: hidden;` style for the large `DIV`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using jQuery, try this:

```
var $targets = $('.awesomeClass'),
    targetHeight = $targets.first().height();

$targets.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if( $this.height() < targetHeight ) {
        targetHeight = $this.height();
    }
});

$targets.height( targetHeight );
```

This code will set the height of all matching elements to the height of the shortest member.

Just make sure all your target elements have the class `awesomeClass`, or whatever class you decide to use, and add an `overflow: hidden;` so the overflowing elements are cut off. This method will remain functional even if you decide to change the number of elements etc.

Comment: How to do when there are four div. Like 2 as same and below that two another, but for the below i need that they both correspond to each other.
Hope you are getting me.
For example.....Div 1 Has 2 column and then Div 2 has other two column.
So what i need is Div 1 follow each other and Div 2 follow each other.
Total i will have approx 10 divs.

Comment: Check this site: http://worldpronews.net78.net/
what i need to do is first check the "World" div and set it's height according to left and right column.
then check for Politics, and so on.
Also, is there a method by which  there should not be any half news on any side.?

Comment: @paz Sorry man, haven't had time to check yet. Can you edit this into your question as I requested before? It'll be more helpful for people who come looking for a reference later on.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have following two `div`'s on the page as:

```
<div class="left">
<ul>/<ul>
</div>

<div class="right">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

You want both of them to have the same height i.e. the minimum out of the two.
Well, its simple with following jQuery Code:

```
var leftHeight = $(".left").height();
var rightHeight = $(".right").height();

if(leftHeight > rightHeight)
{
$(".left").height(rightHeight);
}
else
{
$(".right").height(leftHeight);
}
```

Of course you need to set Overflow-y:hidden, for the `div` and `ul`, so the scroll bar doesn't appear.

It's better to set explicit height, then to remove html elements

Answer (score 0):

Removes elements until the first div height is less than or equal to the second one:

```
while($('#div1').height() > $('#div2').height()) {
    $('#div1').find('li:last-child').remove();
}
```

Comment: Assuming the first `div` will always have more `li` elements and that the number of divs won't change, this method is probably better.

Comment: Well yeah, it's just a general apprach. There will have to be some logic as well, deciding which one is taller.